# Nuance to AWS Connect interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuance

I am looking to try and integrate AWS Connect to Nuance Speech.

Ideally, I would like to use a VXML interface from within Amazon Connect. But Amazon Connect will not support a native VXML interface.

The choices I have are to use either PSTN breakout from Connect to Nuance via a PBX that supports VXML or to pull out a text stream from Amazon connect Lex and pass to Nuance as a text string.

Anyone got any other experience how to do this without having to invest in a PBX to do the XML conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the Voximal or the Voxibot solutions?
You can use an AWS image to instance a VoiceXML interpreter in the Amazon Cloud.
May it could help.